# Ruby for the PIC32 Microcontroller

Tags: ruby, microcontroller, pic

Is there an existing library to write code for the PIC32 in Ruby?

Currently I've been writing code in C to perform tasks on it, but I would love to use Ruby.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is an existing library for that task, but it should be possible (surely not without some effort) to extend [Metasm](http://metasm.cr0.org/) to include a new assembler backend for your processor. It also includes a C parser/compiler.

**EDIT:** I just realized you are looking for a Ruby interpreter on that platform, which I hardly can believe exists.

Answer (score 1):

I also doubt that Ruby on iron exists, but it would be nice to be wrong. :)

If your pic32 can handle an OS that would run Ruby, that might be an option. Otherwise you may be able to prototype a lot of your algorithms in locally run Ruby and then translate them to C on the PIC32.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but according to this [link](http://blog.flyingpic24.com/2015/10/07/mruby/), mruby can run on pic32

> 5. As a consequence, the interpreter is now much reduced in size and can
>      be cross compiled for low cost 32-bit microcontrollers including ….
>      the PIC32 (MX7)! The official repository on GitHub contains already
>      examples for a few embedded platforms including the chipKIT MAX32!

https://github.com/mruby/mruby